# React onChange requires double click to get selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a form that accepts "Yes" or "No" (Radio).

What I want is for it to pass the selected value to a state. I manage to make it work but the problem is that I need to double click the chose for it to register.

The following are the scenario with my current code:
The default value is "No", if I click "Yes", the value is still "No." If I double click "Yes", the value changes to "Yes." If I then click again to "No", the value still remains "Yes" until I double click "No"

These are my current code:

```
//Initialize variables
const [answer,setAnswer] = useState({
        has_commendations: false,
        has_complaints: false      
    })
```

On answer function

```
const onStaticAnswerClick = (e,number) => {
        // Static question number 7
        if(number === 7) {
            setAnswer({
                ...answer,
                has_commendations:Boolean(Number(e.target.value))
              
            })

        }
        
        // Static question number 8
        if(number === 8) {
            setAnswer({
                ...answer,
                has_complaints:Boolean(Number(e.target.value)),

            })
            
        }
    }
```

The radio selection

```
<div className="ml-2 mt-1 d-flex flex-row mt-2">
  <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input 
       className="form-check-input" 
       type="radio" 
        onClick={e => onStaticAnswerClick(e,7)} 
        name="inlineRadioOptions" 
        id="inlineRadio17"
        value={0}
        defaultChecked
  />
  <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineRadio1">No</label>
        </div>
    <div className="form-check form-check-inline ml-3">
      <input 
        className="form-check-input" 
          type="radio" 
           onClick={e => onStaticAnswerClick(e,7)} 
            name="inlineRadioOptions" 
             id="inlineRadio17"
             value={1}
         />

     <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineRadio2">Yes</label>
   </div>
```

I'm really stumped at the moment. Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onClick`, try using `onChange`

```
 <input 
    className="form-check-input" 
    type="radio" 
    onChange={e => onStaticAnswerClick(e,7)} 
    name="inlineRadioOptions" 
    id="inlineRadio17"
    value={1}
     />
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried it now, it sort of worked (Added bonus that I can no longer double click the same button).

The problem now though is that my first click will always be the default value first (e.g. clicking from default "No" to "Yes" will have the value of "No", but going back and forth again between "No" and "Yes" will produce the correct values now.

If I'm going to guess, I need a way for it to register the selected value immediately, e.g. triggering onChange at the first click. Am I correct?

P.S. I flipped the values of Yes(1) and No(0), to accomodate the change.

Comment: Are the 2 radio buttons suppose to be linked? Are there only going to be 2 buttons? Or are you talking about *toggling*?

Comment: Definitely two radio buttons. Apologies, but what do you mean by link?

My radio option looks like this, if my illustration would help: ( ) No   ( ) Yes

Comment: Because only one radio button can be selected at a time, your `if-else` statements doesn't work. It will only contain value.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_radio this is how radio button work. So you got to take a look at how it works before you decide on how you want to use it.

Comment: simple sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-raman-mi9ud?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hello, I tried to implement what you did from the codesandbox but I still can't remove what seems to be a delay on selecting the new value. Could it possibly be a problem on my usage of onChange?

I did try to move my onChange from input to the div, but still the problem persists.

Comment: update your codes, show me what you have changed. You can only update a single object, u cannot use if-else to test number === 7 or number === 8. or if you can, create a codesandbox then i try to edit it directly